# Sqlite: inner join two tables several time

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have two tables:

recipes{`title, ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3`}

list_food{`food, allergy`}

I need to search all the data of the column `food` in the columns `ingredient1`, `ingredient2` and `ingredient3`, in order to obtain the output table - I'd like to see only the recipes that NOT contain `food`.

I've started to write the following part of query, but I need to search food also in ingredient2 and ingredient3 and then I have to exclude all the recipes that contain `food` in one (or more) of the columns

```
SELECT *
FROM recipes
INNER JOIN list_food
ON recipes.ingredient1 = list_food.food
```

Comment: Unrelated: What if a recipe has more than 3 ingredients? (answer to this _may_ indeed be related to the question, though)

Comment: Thank you for the question, I'm doing a test only with simple recipes with 3 ingredients

Comment: I see, now the problem is that you have several columns for ingredients. The first thing that would come to my mind (_if_ you do not want to change the schema) would be to [union](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/) with the same query but on ingeredient2 and 3 and then [distinct](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-select-distinct) that result ... and go from there.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood well (I'm a beginner!). If I do a union of the columns ingredient2 and ingredient3, then how can I search the column food inside?

Comment: You can't do all three at once. You need to aggregate the results for the join on ingredients1, union with results for ingredients2, same for 3, then throw away duplicates. That's why I personally would ask myself if that's the best schema I can come up with.

Comment: Mmm ok I've understood the concept. Maybe I can create new tables?

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the db schema, I'd definitely introduce an additional table to map your ingredients to the recipes.

The schema could look like:

```
recipes{ID, Title, prepTime, ...}
list_food{ID, food, allergy, ...}
mapRecipes2Ingredients{RecID, FoodID}
```

The mapping table contains only the two IDs from your recipes and ingredients, but keeps track of the n-m relationship. This approach would also allow you to have one recipe with 2 ingredients and one with 200.